# After meeting Nick, I've lost power armour

Tags: fallout-4

As part of Nick Valentine's quest line you need to have dogmeat help you searching. When this happened (it happened automatically to me) I had Preston in power armour with me.

He was sent away (and the dialog to send him away appeared) and he was wearing power armour. However once I returned to Sancuary he was no longer wearing the power armour, and there is no power armour icon on my map to indicate where he left it (if anywhere!).

Also, prior to giving him this set of armour, I'd left a previous set outside another random house (because I glitched through the window by sitting on a seat (teleporting myself inside) and that icon is also gone, as I can't recall exactly where it is, I can't go back and get this armour either.

Is there anyway to find these 'lost' armours?

Comment: I play on xbox one, but when I was told to fetch Dogmeat, he was waiting outside (as you experienced), however my follower was not dismissed.

Comment: Did you check Preston's inventory for the pieces? Sometimes a companion will de-equip a piece, which goes to their inventory. Worth a look.

Comment: To add to the weirdness (maybe this was kind of fixed by the patch?) one set of armour has reappeared now in Sancuary, almost inside the wall of one of the houses. I managed to get into it tho :) (I have JUST sent Garvy to the castle tho, so maybe that's why?)

Comment: @Timelord64 Same thing happened to me. Dogmeat doesn't need to be your companion for that quest. He just tags along as a temporary quest-assigned follower if he wasn't already following you.

Answer (score 3):

When companions are dismissed, they get out of their power armor before departing. So Preston's armor is wherever you picked up Nick (probably the Overseers office in Valut 81 if it was your first meeting, or perhaps in the detective agency).

As to the armor you left outside somewhere random, you'll just have to retrace your steps, unfortunately.

Comment: So the first armour I think was when Nick tells you that you need dogmeat, and so this would be at Kellog's house. I've checked both inside and outside and it's definately not there. If anyone can remind me exactly the location you are in when Nick says to get dogmeat (and the game automatically changes followers) that'd be helpful...

Comment: @djsmiley2k Well, the good news is that Power Armor is super common - it's probably easier to just find a new set or seven than it is to try to find the ones that have disappeared on you.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz yeah, I'm just hoping it's level dependant, or maybe quest dependant. I've only just had the giant airship show up (to give you an idea of where I am in the story) and have only seen... 3 sets.

Comment: @djsmiley2k power armor frames are at fixed locations around the wasteland (unless you're interested in fusion core theft shenanigans.) however the *quality* of that power armor is level dependent. So you'll find better stuff.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've dismissed companions in power armor and returned to Sanctuary to see them still wearing it. I'll get back to you if I note it happening again.

Comment: @DCShannon Yeah I was wondering about that too. I was pretty sure I'd seen an answer to another question about Power Armor transportation where it was specifically suggested to give it to your companion and dismiss them if you want to return it to a settlement without actually taking it yourself.

Comment: @Iszi That might have been my answer, at this point. Pretty sure I wrote one of those.

Answer (score 1):

As you figured out were the Armor, Preston was wearing, is, I answer the question about the other armor.

The Icon only appears for the armor you had left last. The position of all other armors have to be memorized (I recommend leaving them all in one settlement). So, you have to search your Power armor by going to said house. 
If you leave a power armor outside one of your settlements it can get stolen. If you really can't find it, than this propably happened. I don't know if you can get it back by finding the thief, but even if you find him, you would have to get him out of your armor somehow.

Answer (score 1):

I've dismissed a companion in power armor and had them wear it all the way back to the settlement multiple times. However, I've heard from a few people, including you, that they occasionally remove the armor on the way.

If this happens, the only way you even *might* find the armor is by tracing the path they would have taken from where you dismissed them to where you sent them.

This means that the two armors you are referring to are probably in the same situation: out in the world *somewhere*, standing around. Armor will disappear after a few days if left outside of a settlement, so good luck finding them.

If you really need the suit, you should probably load a previous save.